# Face book video share

Tags: facebook, video, share

i am trying to share video, but somehow i am not able to share it
i can only see image, title description but not video

following is the meta tag i have use

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxx-fb id-xxx">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/fbshare.php">
<meta property="og:title" content="meta title">
<meta property="og:description" content="meta desc...">
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:image" content="http:path to image/example.jpg">
<meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/example.swf">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="398">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="224">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="example">
```

let me know what things i have to set or update it

Comment: Can you show the code how you share the video? Or do you use the FB Share dialog?

Comment: Hello @Tobi

here i have post URL

http://letzchat.mrpvision.com/fbsharesub.php?test=2

you can see, i have integrated all "og" meta tag